# Origin of a ROS map representation

Tags: datagrid, maps, ros, robotics

I am working with ROS and its map_server node.

I dont understand what the origin metadata info of a map means (conceptually). According to the official documetation:

> origin : The 2-D pose of the lower-left pixel in the map, as (x, y,
>   yaw), with yaw as counterclockwise rotation (yaw=0 means no rotation).
>   Many parts of the system currently ignore yaw.

It is not the initial pose of the robot? But It establish some area of interest of the occupance grid?

Why this value is so important for the Navigation Stack?

Can you give me a simple example of the same map with different origins?

Answer (score 0):

Origin is generally the position of the robot at the beginning of the program. So yes the initial pose of the robot. When I've used it, it could be used as the original position of the robot. Generally, when using origin you create a deep copy of the current position.

```
def initPose(self):
    origin = copy.deepcopy(self._current)

    q = [origin.orientation.x,
        origin.orientation.y,
        origin.orientation.z,
        origin.orientation.w]  # quaternion nonsense

    (roll, pitch, yaw) = euler_from_quaternion(q)
    return (self._current.position.x, self._current.position.y, yaw)

    # self._odom_list.waitForTransform('YOUR_STRING_HERE', 'YOUR_STRING_HERE', rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(1.0))
```

But I've also used origin to be the origin of a function.

```
def navToPose(self, goal):
# self._odom_list.waitForTransform('map', 'base_footprint', rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(1.0))
# transGoal = self._odom_list.transformPose('base_footprint', goal) # transform the nav goal from the global coordinate system to the robot's coordinate system
    origin = copy.deepcopy(self._current)

    q = [origin.orientation.x,
         origin.orientation.y,
         origin.orientation.z,
         origin.orientation.w]  # quaternion nonsense

    (roll, pitch, yaw) = euler_from_quaternion(q)
     qc = [self._current.orientation.x,
           self._current.orientation.y,
           self._current.orientation.z,
           self._current.orientation.w]
    (rollc, pitchc, yawc) = euler_from_quaternion(qc)
    x = goal.pose.position.x
    y = goal.pose.position.y
    cx = origin.position.x
    cy = self._current.position.y

    print('current', cx, cy)
    print(x, y)
    theta = math.atan2(y-cy, x-cx)
    print ('angle is ', theta)
    self.rotate(theta)
    distance = (((x - cx) ** 2) + ((y - cy) ** 2)) ** .5
    print ('distance is ', distance)
    self.driveStraight(0.5, distance)
```

So generally, I've used it more as another variable.

Depending on how the Occupancy grid is done. Sometime the origin will refer to where it started on the grid. Allowing the program to know if it still on the map. This can create issues shown here: https://answers.ros.org/question/285602/static-map-corner-at-origin-for-navigation-stack/ (at least from what I've experienced)

For more information on the nav stack go: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation
and here: https://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~nardi/Didattica/CAI/matdid/robot-programming-ROS-introduction-to-navigation.pdf

Answer (score 0):

From the ros message definition (http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/MapMetaData.html) :

```
 # The origin of the map [m, m, rad].  This is the real-world pose of the
 # cell (0,0) in the map.
```

That is the coordinate of the lower left corner of your map *in the reference frame*.

The robot and its position have no relationship with the map origin.

There is some details and nice illustration here : https://answers.ros.org/question/205521/robot-coordinates-in-map/